# Magento 1.9.2 - show "category page & layout" on front home page (RWD theme)

Tags: magento, layout, html, categories

How to show exactly the same Category Page on Homepage?

- without banners, without home boxes, no 1 column layout
- just full Category Page (i.e. with sidebar, filters, layered nav, 2-3 columns layout, product listing), and NOT only product from particular category - again, standard category page to be shown, just like you click on category link.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Find out the ID of the category you want to to display, creating it if necessary. Then go to `System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages` in your admin and enter the following for the `Default web url` option: catalog/category/view/id/99 (where 99 is the id of the category).
2. Create a normal CMS page, assign it as the homepage in `System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages` then call a category list.phtml with

   `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="99" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Comment: `+1` @WombleGold  **1)** 1st solution works OK (it includes sidebar, filters, swatches, layout, all). A **mistake** was to select the most "top-level (root) category" (Default Category) - this was _only_ showing products.  **2)** 2nd solution useless - it "just" takes products from "catogory" specified and list them. **3)** If you would like to show how to re-create homepage with "exactly same view of categery" i.e: sidebar, layout, swatches, etc **for 2nd solution** - please do it. But it might need more customisation in places like `category.xml`, maybe `page.xml`, or some Layout Update XML.